# Setar valor na sessão em Banco de Dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, session

Estou tentando usar uma sessão de banco de dados

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para setar a sessão na coluna específica também

Estou tentando assim

```
Session::put([
      'login' =>  $login
     ]);
```

Mas não salva nada, percebo que quando eu logo ele coloca os outros valores, como o ip, id, mas o login que eu gostaria de inserir também não salva e também gostaria de saber em que momento ele insere os outros valores

Comment: Se tem pode exemplificar isso até chegar essa conclusão? Tipo o código passo a passo?

Comment: Sessão usando usando database?

Comment: Tipo: Eu gostaria de saber como faço para setar a sessão na coluna específica também? tem como explicar porque talvez você não tenha entendido como funciona!

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo. Não entendi como funciona direito, porque quando logo no sistema, ele insere os valores, não sei em que momento